# Slow streaming over WiFi (local devices)?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

I'm trying to stream Macbook desktop (AirPlay) with AppleTV over TP-Link TL-WR940N router and the connection is pretty bad. I also tried to transfer a movie clip between Windows PC and the AppleTV - also bad - which gave me a hint that the problem might be in the router. I tried with a new router - same result.

It doesn't make sense, since it's a local network, 
and all devices have 100mbps connection. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/TL-WR940N.html & https://www.tp-link.com/us/download/TL-WR940N.html show your router uses 2.4GHz & 5GHz WiFi channels. The latter allows more bandwidth;  also, bonding multiple channels together for even more bandwith, but 5GHz has shorter range & less penetration. A) What channel(s) do(es) your router use? B) What channels do other nearby use per a smartphone app? C) Is the router avoiding used channels? D) Did you use bonding? Please click [edit] & answer by expanding the question above. Neighbor interference is a frequent cause of slow WiFi speed.

Comment: 100Mbps is the theoretical speed of the switch ports; different versions of your router have different WiFi maximum speeds. Which version of the TL-WR940N do you have? Version 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6? Please advise by looking underneath for the serial number plate which also shows the version number, then click on [edit] and update your question so everyone can see this important information.